# How to check flash memory for ECC errors from the Linux command line

Tags: linux, embedded, flash-memory, ecc

Is there a way to check flash memory for ECC errors from the Linux command line? Note that I do not want to correct ECC errors. I just want to detect errors and list page addresses where they occur.

Comment: I have used memtest86 for this in the past. You have to compile a small C program-- unless someone has packaged it up, now.